# Does the thickness of germanium dioxide affect the amount of infrared light that passes through it?

Tags: optics

Furthermore, what properties of germanium cause it to behave in this manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thickness of any material will affect the amount of IR radiation that passes through it. The equation for the attenuation of radiation thru matter is given by this equation. $I = I_0\ e^{-kt}$ where k is the attenuation coefficient for radiation through the material and t is the thickness of the material.

Germanium dioxide is transparent to IR radiation but that doesn't mean 100% of IR passes through a thin layer of GeO2. There will be a small amount that gets attenuated. The equation above holds but k will be very small. Still, the thickness will determine how much IR passes through it.

Comment: Relevant reading: [Bouguer-Lambert-Beer law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer%E2%80%93Lambert_law).

Comment: It seems like this is typically used for xrays, where can I find the attenuation coefficient of infrared through germanium?

Comment: https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/XrayMassCoef/ElemTab/z32.html

Comment: Above is for X-rays. For IR try this site: https://lightmachinery.com/media/1541/germanium.pdf. or this site: http://www.ioffe.ru/SVA/NSM/Semicond/Ge/optic.html

Comment: For anyone else reading this, this website has some additional explanation: https://www.nde-ed.org/EducationResources/CommunityCollege/Radiography/Physics/attenuationCoef.htm